# Angular - How to test if an error was thrown from an observable error function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine, observable

I have this nested subscription in a function:

```
myFunc() {
    this.userService.isLoggedIn().subscribe(isLoggedIn => {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            this.otherService.post({}).subscribe({
                next: response => {
                    // do stuff
                },
                error: err => {
                    // do stuff
                    throw new UserException(err)
                },
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to write a unit test that expects myFunc to throw UserException if `otherService.post` responds with an error.
I am trying with this:

```
it('should rethrow error', () => {
    const thrownError = new HttpErrorResponse({})
    mockUserService.isLoggedIn.and.returnValue(of(true))
    mockOtherService.post.and.returnValue(throwError(() => thrownError))
    fixture.detectChanges()

    // clicking on the UI to call component.myFunc

    expect(mockOtherService.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith({})
    expect(() => component.myFunc()).toThrow(new UserException(thrownError))
}
```

But it fails because `myFunc` does not throw an exception. Why is that?

Comment: never use nested subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

#### Nested Functions

Consider the following code and notice that even though there's an error thrown "inside" `function one`, `function one` will never throw an error on its own.

```ts
function one(){
  console.log("ONE");

  const two = () => {
    console.log("TWO");
    throw "This is an error";
  }

  return two;
}

console.log("Calling function one");
one();
console.log("Done with function one");
```

The error is only ever seen later when that internal function is actually called:

```ts
const two = one();
// the following throws an error:
two();
```

#### myFunc doesn't throw an error:

That's how asynchronous code works. It defines some code (like `two` above) that doesn't get called right away, it gets called sometime later.

By the time either `next` or `error` is called from `{next: /*...*/, error: /*...*/}`, the function that returned the `next` and `error` functions (myFunc) has already run and been popped off of the call stack.

So, in this case, your test is correct to note that `myFunc` doesn't throw an error (because it doesn't).

I'm not sure delving into the various testing libraries and harnesses for RxJS is in scope for such an answer (maybe somebody else will take on that task?).

---

#### An Aside: Refactoring RxJS

In general, you shouldn't nest subscriptions. Avoiding nested callbacks is one of the core features of both Promises and Observables for asynchronous workflows.

Here's how I might write `myFunc` instead:

```ts
myFunc() {
  
  this.userService.isLoggedIn().pipe(

    filter(isLoggedIn => !!isLoggedIn),
    mergeMap(_ => this.otherService.post({}))

  ).subscribe({
    next: response => { /* do stuff */ },
    error: err => {
        // do stuff
        throw new UserException(err);
    }
  })

}
```